# Error while building through ANT "package com.ibm.jsse2 does not exist"

Tags: java, xml, ant, javac

I am trying to run my build.xml using ANT.

It is throwing an error:

```
package com.ibm.jsse2 does not exist
```

Using eclipse I am building with the same script.

If I try to run in a command prompt it is showing the following error:

```
F:\New folder\Clinical>ant -f build_MEDCOM_ear.xml medcom.ear
Buildfile: F:\New folder\Clinical\build_MEDCOM_ear.xml

clear:

build:
    [mkdir] Created dir: F:\New folder\Clinical\web\WEB-INF\classes
    [javac] F:\New folder\Clinical\build_MEDCOM_ear.xml:69: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=
last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 1430 source files to F:\New folder\Clinical\web\WEB-INF\classes
    [javac] F:\New folder\Clinical\src\com\igi\phr\eligibility\util\HTTPXMLProxy.java:116: package com.ibm.jsse2 does not exist
    [javac]             Security.addProvider(new com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2());
    [javac]                                                       ^
    [javac] F:\New folder\Clinical\src\com\igi\phr\eprescription\web\proxy\AuthenticatingXmlServerProxy.java:273: package com.ibm.jsse2
 does not exist
    [javac]             Security.addProvider(new com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2());
    [javac]                                                       ^
    [javac] F:\New folder\Clinical\src\com\igi\phr\eprescription\web\proxy\DirectoryXmlServerProxy.java:139: package com.ibm.jsse2 does
 not exist
    [javac]             Security.addProvider(new com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2());
    [javac]                                                       ^
    [javac] F:\New folder\Clinical\src\com\igi\phr\eprescription\web\test\EprescriptionTest.java:120: package com.ibm.jsse2 does not ex
ist
    [javac]             Security.addProvider(new com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2());
    [javac]                                                       ^
    [javac] F:\New folder\Clinical\src\com\igi\phr\payment\cr\tcp\GetiClient.java:50: package com.ibm.jsse2 does not exist
    [javac]                     Security.addProvider(new com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2());
    [javac]                                                               ^
    [javac] F:\New folder\Clinical\src\com\igi\phr\payment\cr\tcp\GetiClient.java:84: package com.ibm.jsse2 does not exist
    [javac]             Security.addProvider(new com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2());
    [javac]                                                       ^
    [javac] F:\New folder\Clinical\src\com\igi\phr\payment\cr\unittest\GetiClientTest.java:62: package com.ibm.jsse2 does not exist
    [javac]             Security.addProvider(new com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2());
    [javac]                                                       ^
    [javac] F:\New folder\Clinical\src\com\igi\phr\payment\multipass\util\MPConnector.java:1431: package com.ibm.jsse2 does not exist
    [javac]         Security.addProvider(new com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2());
    [javac]                                               ^
    [javac] F:\New folder\Clinical\src\com\igi\phr\payment\vendor\skipjack\tcpConnection\SJConnector.java:328: package com.ibm.jsse2 do
es not exist
    [javac]         Security.addProvider(new com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2());
    [javac]                                               ^
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 9 errors

BUILD FAILED
F:\New folder\Clinical\build_MEDCOM_ear.xml:69: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 5 seconds
```

Comment: You will have to include the JAR where the class `com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2` exists in your ant build.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi    Could you please tell me where I have to include this com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2. in Ant build file or Web-INF/Classes?

Comment: I believe that this is included in your IBM container???

Comment: @BuhakeSindi Hi.. Same build.xml is working in my developers machine using eclipse.

Comment: Ok, you haven't specified which environment you're running your `build.xml`. Plus, is your developers machine's configurations **identical** to the environment where you're building your code with Ant?

Comment: I am working on windows7 machine with JDK1.5 7 ANT 1.84. My developers also working with same configuration. for developers it is throwing below warning but is generating ear file.          Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Comment: And the one where you're getting the error, which environment is this?

Comment: No, environment means "Development", "QA", "Production". I've already assumed that your local machine is different from the environment where you're getting the error.

Comment: yes.. I am checking locally in my machine.. once it is success I have to send that ear file to QA environment.

Comment: Hi.. I got solution. My Developers set JAVA_HOME path form IBM Websphere java path as C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java.  Now I have changed env variable path of JAVA. it is working good and generating ear... Thanks alot @Buhake Sindi.....